# How to do colspan and rowspan to jqGrid header?

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-ui, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

Kindly see the following image.

[image]

How would I achieve the same span in cols and rows ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the demo for the table structure you are looking for

[Demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

In left panel, go to 'Frozen Cols.Group Header(new)'. Under that go to 'Group Header - with colspan style' & check out grid configuration.

You need to call 'setGroupHeaders' method like this:

```
jQuery("#id").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: true,   
  groupHeaders:[{startColumnName: 'Permanent', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'group 1'}]
});
```

[Documentation Link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar)